# C's strange pointer arithmetics

Tags: c, pointers

I was working on pointers. I saw a code snippet but I couldn't understand how it works.
The strange thing is that when the `k` function is executed, the expression `y = 2` doesn't seem to work. Because the output is `y = 1` instead of `y = 2`.
Any idea about this?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void k(void){
    int x;
    *(&x+5) += 7;
}

void main(void){
    int y = 1;
    y = 1;
    k();
    y = 2;
    printf("y = %d", y);
}
```

CPU:AMD Ryzen 7 5800H with Radeon Graphics (16) @ 3.200GHz
OS: Arch Linux x86_64
Compiler: GCC (Version: 12.1.1)
compile command: gcc a.c -o a

Comment: This is undefined behaviour. You've written past the end of `x`.

Comment: do you know what `*(&x+5)` contains? If you don't, why are you touching an area not belonging to you?

Comment: Compile with warnings: `warning: ‘x’ is used uninitialized`

Comment: Where did you get this from, [Robert Traister](https://wozniak.ca/blog/2018/06/25/1/index.html)?

Comment: Pure technically, ignoring the undefined behaviour: `x` is placed somewhere on the stack, you take the address of and move five `int`s away from. On a top-down stack, you'd be accessing some element placed on the stack before. Which one depends on alignment requirements of the variables on the stack (-> padding), calling convention, registers to be saved, etc. – though as a void(void) function there shouldn't be much extra information on the stack...

Comment: Side note: `void main(void)` is none of the valid (by the standard) main functions for a hosted environment (i.e. running on an OS); should be `int main(void)` instead.

Comment: @fsyscall Please specify processor architecture, OS, compiler and compiler options. Otherwise we can only speculate about the effect of UB.

Comment: The odd thing here is that one would expect the result to be either `y = 2` or a crash.  Ignore what the C standard says; there's no plausible way for the assembly generated for `k` to _prevent the assignment `y = 2` from occurring_.  (On the computer where I'm typing this, gcc  makes `k` do various things at different optimization levels which may or may not have the effect of crashing on return, but regardless, the actual variable `y` is eliminated and the assembly for the `printf` call is the equivalent of `printf("y = %d", 2)`.)

Comment: @zwol Of course there is a way. Depending on the size of `int` and the size of the stack frame, `*(&x+5) += 7` _might_ overwrite the return address of `k`. Depending on the amount of code being generated for `y=2`, the new return address _might_ point to `printf("y = %d", y)`, effectively causing `y=2` to be skipped. `*(&x+5) += 7` has obviously been crafted to do something like that; but it will only work for a _very_ specific combination of processor architecture, compiler and compiler options.

Comment: @RuudHelderman 
CPU:AMD Ryzen 7 5800H with Radeon Graphics (16) @ 3.200GHz
OS: Arch Linux x86_64
Compiler: GCC (Version: 12.1.1)
Compile command: gcc a.c -o a

Comment: @RuudHelderman Oh, very clever, yes, I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by others, this statement suffers from [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

```
*(&x+5) += 7;
```

Memory address `&x+5` is outside the bounds of variable `x`. Writing to that address is a *very bad idea.*

OP's code sample exploits certain C compiler implementation details.
Probably **educational**; it can be used to demonstrate how hackers can exploit missing bounds checks to change the designed behavior of a program.

It is interesting enough to investigate the actual behavior of this program.
I will assume the program has been compiled by GCC with default settings on a 64-bit Linux distro on Intel x64 processor architecture (i.e. [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)).
Pointers are 64 bits (8 bytes), `int` is 32 bits (4 bytes).

Variable `x` is located on the stack. During execution of `k()`, the stack looks like this:

```
+--------+----------------------------------------------------+  TOP OF STACK
| rsp+0  | unused; 16-byte alignment filler                   | <--- rsp
+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
| rsp+4  | x                                                  | <--- &x
+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
| rsp+8  | reserved; least significant 32 bits of stack guard |
+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
| rsp+12 | reserved; most significant 32 bits of stack guard  |
+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
| rsp+16 | least significant 32 bits of saved base pointer    | <--- rbp
+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
| rsp+20 | most significant 32 bits of saved base pointer     |
+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
| rsp+24 | least significant 32 bits of return address of k() | <--- &x+5
+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
| rsp+28 | most significant 32 bits of return address of k()  |
+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
| rsp+32 | start of stack frame of main()                     |
+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

`&x+5` is a memory address that is 20 bytes away from `&x` (because `sizeof(int)` is 4).
That happens to be the location of the return address of `k()`.
`*(&x+5) += 7` will increase the return address by 7.
That will have its effect when returning from `k()` to `main()`.
Here is `objdump` output of `main()`:

```
void main(void)
{
  45:   55                      push   rbp
  46:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  49:   48 83 ec 10             sub    rsp,0x10
        int y = 1;
  4d:   c7 45 fc 01 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1
        y = 13;
  54:   c7 45 fc 0d 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0xd
        k();
  5b:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   60 <main+0x1b>
        y = 2;
  60:   c7 45 fc 02 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x2
        printf("y = %d\n", y);
  67:   8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
  6a:   89 c6                   mov    esi,eax
  6c:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    rdi,[rip+0x0]        # 73 <main+0x2e>
  73:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  78:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   7d <main+0x38>
}
  7d:   90                      nop
  7e:   c9                      leave
  7f:   c3                      ret
```

The program is supposed to return from `k()` at offset `60` (the start of `y = 2`), but instead, it will return at offset `67` (the start of `printf("y = %d\n", y)`).

In other words, after returning from `k()`, the program will skip `y = 2` and continue from `printf("y = %d\n", y)`, printing `y = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

There is undefined behavior (UB) on the `*(&x+5) += 7;` line. When there is UB, the program can do anyting including formatting your hard drive and outputting `y=1`.

To learn what is happening under the hood, you can check the assembly [output](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:4,endLineNumber:8,positionColumn:4,positionLineNumber:8,selectionStartColumn:4,selectionStartLineNumber:8,startColumn:4,startLineNumber:8),source:%27%23include%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0Avoid+k(void)%7B%0A++++int+x%3B%0A++++*(%26x%2B5)+%2B%3D+7%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main(void)%7B%0A++++int+y+%3D+1%3B%0A++++y+%3D+1%3B%0A++++k()%3B%0A++++y+%3D+2%3B%0A++++printf(%22y+%3D+%25d%22,+y)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:28.561215370866847,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g112,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:12,endLineNumber:31,positionColumn:12,positionLineNumber:31,selectionStartColumn:12,selectionStartLineNumber:31,startColumn:12,startLineNumber:31),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:38.10545129579983,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+11.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

Answer (score 0):

The function `k()` invokes undefined behaviour.

This is because first you declare a local variable `x`. After this you try to add `7` to the address `&x+5` which goes past the end of `x`.

Comment: `x` being uninitialised is irrelevant in this case as it is never read – 7 is added to that other address where we have no idea (seen from C point of view) what might be there...

Comment: "`y` is a local variable in `main()` so calling `k()` won't have any affect on it." But with UB, anything is possible. In OP's case, `*(&x+10)` gives `k()` full access to `y`.